# Mysql skip-name-resolve

Tags: mysql

I had recently purchased a new server, and transferred all my accounts via WHM Transfer.

The problem is that when WHM takes a daily backup, it outputs are message such as

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: There is no such grant defined for user 'abc' on host 'myhostname'
```

The problem is solved when I remove skip-name-resolve from my my.cnf file. Tough I dont find any differences in the speed (when I dont add it), it is often mentioned in forums that adding skip-name-resolve optimizes Mysql Performance.

Does adding skip-name-resolve really help, if one has a Dedicated server?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how many clients are connecting to the server and how often. If you only have one server connecting to MySQL (e.g. the local host) there is really no benefit by setting this option because MySQL does cache the result from the DNS lookup for some time, so you only really incur the performance penalty at the start.

If you have lots of hosts connecting to your MySQL server, and many connections, you can certainly see a benefit (I have seen benefits in environments where we have 25 web servers hitting a DB server that is handling 500 q/sec, with a new connection for each web request).

You do have to adjust all the grants to use IP addresses instead of host names if you go this route, e.g. to fix your above issue:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'abc'@'myhostname';
```

Take the output of that and change the host name to IP address to create all the same grants based on the IP address. You can then revoke the host-based grants.

Comment: In case, if we add grants for IP address, while connecting to the DB, do you need to specify the IP address instead of the 'DB name'/'DB user'

Comment: Nope, since the grants by IP deal with the *client's* address it shouldn't affect the way the clients are connecting to the server (they can continue to specify `localhost` as before and should work).

Comment: If you connect specifying localhost in the host parameter then your MySQL user should have rights as localhost.